# Как проверить из скрипта на python 3.x, запущен ли другой python скрипт?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как проверить из скрипта на python 3.x, запущен ли другой python скрипт?

Есть два скрипта **sript1.py** и **script2.py**. Нужно из скрипта **script1.py** проверить работает ли на том же компьютере **script2.py**.

Решение должно работать под любой os.

Comment: Под какой операционкой?

Comment: Linux, Windows, MacOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно проверять с помощью `psutil`:

   ```
   def verification():
       for pid in psutil.pids():
           p = psutil.Process(pid)
           if p.name() == "python.exe" and len(p.cmdline()) > 1 and "script2.py" in p.cmdline()[1]:
               print ("running")
   ```
2. Можно использовать [lockfile](https://pythonhosted.org/lockfile/lockfile.html). Правда, не 100% метод. Если приложение крашнется, то это нужно потом обработать как-то.

Comment: Немного модифицировал код и проверил на Windows - работает  --  `def isRunningPythonScript(scriptName):

 for pid in psutil.pids():
  p = psutil.Process(pid)
  
  if (  "python" in p.name() ):
   
   for item in p.cmdline():
    if ( scriptName in item ):
     print(p.name(), item)
     return True

 return False`

Comment: @YuriyTigiev ну вот и отлично (:

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет библиотека PSI

```
import pwd
import psi
import psi.process
myProcessName="process2" 
for p in psi.process.ProcessTable().values():
    if myProcessName in p.command:
        <действия>
```

Для более сложного поиска можно использовать регулярные выражения.

Также можно использовать psutil

```
import psutil
import os 
def is_running(script):
    for q in psutil.process_iter():
        if q.name().startswith('python'):
            if len(q.cmdline())>1 and script in q.cmdline()[1] and q.pid !=os.getpid():
                print("'{}' Process is already running".format(script))
                return True

    return False
```

Comment: Вряд ли имя script.py можно отловить через процессы. Там будет просто python.exe.

Comment: Мне не просто нужно отловить python, а нужно видеть какой был стартовый скрипт.